# How to read variable in ConfigMap which is in a k8s namespace with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes

I have a flask.py and I want to put my variable into configmap.yaml of k8s.

However I dont know how to use k8s module of python to read my configmap in k8s. Do I just need to use `os.getenv()` or use `from kubernetes import client, config` ?

Comment: This is normally declared in the deployment. There are different approaches possible. The configmap values can be exposed to the pod in environment variables which you can read with `os.getenv()` in your Python program. It's also possible to mount configmap entries as files which you can read from your program. Either way your program should not have to interact with kubernetes, its more maintainable to keep your program unaware of the kubernetes.

Comment: @Erik I use helm to create the yaml files, so I just need to write variable in values.yaml and use it in my deployment.yaml, right ? And my python program just need to let my variable to write as `a = os.getenv()`

Comment: Yes that's the general idea. You can find more about the syntactic details here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/